# matplotlib set legend title position ignored when saving figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

When adding a title to a legend that is centre aligned, the title is offset.  I corrected this using the `set_position` command.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([], [], label='line')
legend = plt.legend(title='legend\ntitle')
legend.get_title().set_ha('center')
legend.get_title().set_position((20, 0))
plt.show()

plt.savefig('legend_test.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
```

[image]

However when this is exported the set_position is ignored and the title is shifted to its original position.

[image]

Is this a bug or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, (it works fine this way):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([], [], label='line')
legend = plt.legend(title='legend\ntitle')
plt.savefig('legend_test.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
```

[image]